# Error while executing "npm start" commnad..?

Tags: javascript

```
PS D:\New folder\html\git\simplefolio> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abhis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-22T11_56_28_193Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\New folder\html\git\simplefolio>
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript has Ham is to Hamster: Completely unrelated. Tag removed.

Answer (score 1):

Check `script` in your `package.json`, it might be missing 'start'. Check [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts) out for more details.